# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I am trying to use the integral test on the series $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)^2}.$$ I am not sure how to evaluate the integral. Any hints?

Comment: The change of variable $x=e^t$ and the inequality $e^t>t$ yield $$\int\frac{dx}{\ln(x)^2}=\int\frac{e^tdt}{t^2}>\int\frac{dt}t,$$ from which one can conclude.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\ln x\right)^2}
\end{equation}

you should be able to show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}-\ln x$ is positive for $x\ge2$. (Just find the minimum value of $f(x)$.)

Therefore for $n\ge2$ it's true that
$0<\ln n<\sqrt{n}$.

So $\dfrac{1}{(\ln{n})^2}>\dfrac{1}{n}$

Therefore the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\ln x\right)^2}$ diverges by direct comparison to the harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the integral test, you need to figure out whether or not the integral $$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} dx $$ converges or not. To do this, I would suggest making the substitution $u = \ln (x),$ then note that $du = 1/x dx$ and that $x = e^u$. Plug all of this in and go to work!

Answer (score 2):

One may onserve that
$$
0<\ln x<\sqrt{x} ,\qquad x>2,
$$ giving
$$
0<(\ln x)^2<x, \qquad x>2,
$$ then

> $$
> \int_2^M \frac{dx}x < \int_2^M \frac{dx}{(\ln x)^2}, \qquad M>2,
> $$

thus, by letting $M \to \infty$, the initial integral **diverges**.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is clearly bounded below by the harmonic series starting from 2 (since $\ln(n)^2 < n$), so it diverges.

Comment: I'll grant that $\ln(n) < n,$ but how does one prove that $(\ln n)^2 < n$?

Comment: @treble If you know that $\ln(n)<n$, then $\ln(\sqrt{n}) < \sqrt{n}$ and hence $\frac12\ln(n)<\sqrt{n}$, hence $(\ln(n))^2<4n$.

Comment: Regardless it only needs to hold asymptotically, which is quite easy to show.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). Note that 
$$2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{(\ln 2^n)^2}=\frac{2^n}{n^2(\ln 2)^2}$$so that $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ does not converge (terms don't go to zero) and hence the original series diverges.